# show and hide div and reload function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function to hide and show div

```
function showDiv(popupName) {   

    if (popupName.is(':hidden')) {  
        var hid = document.getElementById("filter");
        hid.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        var hid = document.getElementById("filter");
        hid.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

is there any ways to reload hide div when we move other page and come back hide div page?

Comment: We need to see your DOM. And you should explain what exactly are you trying to do. Further more you can take this duplicated command `var hid = document.getElementById("filter");` out from the condition

Comment: What do you mean by "Other tag"?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(selector).toggle()` instead.

[**DOCUMENTATION**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

> Display or hide the matched elements.
>
> version added: 1.0

So, if your div id is `filter` your function becomes:

```
function showDiv(popupName) { 
    $("#filter").toggle();
}
```